# How is the boundary in product spaces defined?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, several-complex-variables

The general question: how is the boundary defined in product spaces? Given two topological spaces $X,Y$, I'd say that $\partial(X\times Y)=\partial X\times\partial Y$. But looking at what follows it doesn't seem to be right:

[image]

Clearly here $\partial_0 P=\partial\Delta_1\times\cdots\times\partial\Delta_n$, but it doesn't coincide with $\partial P$.

So, what's the difference between $\partial P$ and $\partial_0 P$?

Comment: Given a subset $A$ of a topological space, there is an associated set $\partial A$ called the boundary of $A$ which is defined as $\partial A = \overline{A}\setminus A^{\circ}$. Note, if $A$ is a product, such as $A = X\times Y$, the above definition still works. In particular, we don't have to *define* the boundary of a product, it is already defined; what you want is a way to relate $\partial(X\times Y)$ to $\partial X$ and $\partial Y$.

Comment: Many thanks. Yeah, I know. But how can I relate them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can see that that $\partial(X\times Y) \neq \partial X\times\partial Y$ by considering $X = Y = (0, 1) \subset \mathbb{R}$. On the one hand, $\partial(X\times Y)$ is the boundary of the unit square, while $\partial X\times \partial Y$ consists of the four corner points.

The relationship between the boundary of a product and the boundaries of the factors is

$$\partial(X\times Y) = (\partial X\times\overline{Y}) \cup (\overline{X}\times\partial Y).$$

For the example above, $\partial X = \partial Y = \{0, 1\}$ and $\overline{X} = \overline{Y} = [0, 1]$, so

$$\partial(X\times Y) = (\{0, 1\}\times[0, 1])\cup([0, 1]\times\{0,1\})$$

which indeed is the boundary of the unit square: $\{0, 1\}\times[0, 1]$ gives the two vertical sides, and $[0, 1]\times\{0, 1\}$ gives the two horizontal sides.

Note that in this example, $\partial X\times \partial Y \subseteq \partial(X\times Y)$. This is also true in general, as can be seen from the formula above; in fact, $\partial X\times\partial Y = (\partial X\times\overline{Y})\cap(\overline{X}\times\partial Y)$.

Comment: @ Michael Albanese:many thanks!

Comment: Any explanation why this *is* the Leibniz rule for differentiation of a product?

Comment: @fosco What are your thoughts regarding this old question of yours? I've wanted a clearer understanding in terms of higher nonsense for a while, but I am still dissatisfied. You seem like the perfect person to ask, too.

Comment: After so many years I understood that it's a very deep problem, if only you allow yourself to look into it. I will be back working at "differential 2-rigs" soon, I hope.